# The placement of database files in a shared folder

Tags: sql-server

Is it a normal practice with *MS SQL Server* to place databases in remote shared folders on a fast local network rather than on the physical HDD where the server software is installed? What problems shall one fear that local placement avoids? For example, can a network glitch cause `.mdf` and `.ldf` to become inconsistent through successful modificaion of the one and failure to modify the other?

**EDIT:**
Whereas *Microsoft* recommends employment of *Storage-Area Network* (*SAN*) or *SCSI* instead of simple shared folders, could you please tell me the disadvantages of the latter?

Comment: No, this is not a normal practice.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key differentiator between the recommended locations (e.g. local storage, a SAN, or an iSCSI-based network) and a network share is quite simply, ***redundancy***.  All of the recommended approaches provide an option for redundant paths for I/O to take to persistent storage.

For instance, you can [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) local storage, providing redundancy if any disk fails.  With either the SAN or iSCSI-based network storage approaches, these technologies use [Multipath Input/Output (MPIO)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619734%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) drivers, providing redundancy to the storage.

A network drive, in contrast, does not employ or allow for any redundant I/O paths.  If a [Network Interface Controller (NIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) fails on either end, the share likely disappears.  Even if you have multiple NICs, there will still be a brief outage as a different IP address will now host that share, so any data sent to the old/failed IP will timeout and disappear.  Basically a network share wasn't designed with this level of redundancy, and a loss of data mid stream may corrupt your database (or worse just get lost without a trace).  The whole point of a database is to reliably store data and a network share brings that whole *reliable* aspect into question.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice for production, but for reporting and staging you can use, Even though SAN and iSCSI are related to a network share. As Dan Guzman(who commented below question) Microsoft recommends keeping the files on SAN, Local Server or iSCSI.

[image]

But if you are using a Network share then that causes a single point of failure.

Comment: re:*single point of failure*: what kind of failure? Can it leave the database files in a corrupt state or not, or will all work again as soon as the network comes online?

Comment: So lets think about the server where the network share is placed, If that server goes down then your database is not accessible also it may be going to corrupt.

Comment: Why cannot the same happen with a SAN, if it suddently goes down?

Comment: You should be able to easily find online a "typical entry-level SAN" and see a diagram that answers why SANs don't easily go down. They are built with multiple redundant components because a SAN is at the core of many enterprise server technologies (including databases). High availability is at the core of a SAN admin's job.